# error C2440: 'type cast' : cannot convert from 'overloaded-function' to

Tags: c++, function, visual-studio-2012, casting

I have a piece of code which worked fine on a previous projet. A part of it was even copied from a working demo project and I don't know how I can have this error on a new project now.
When compiling, I have the following error :

```
1>d:\visual studio 2012\netsdk_poc\mfc_netsdk2\mfc_netsdk2\netsdkfunctions.cpp(33): error C2440: 'type cast' : cannot convert from 'overloaded-function' to 'fDisConnect'
```

The code :

```
class CNetSDKFunctions{

void __stdcall DisConnectBackCallFunc(LONG lLoginID, char *pchDVRIP, 
                                  LONG nDVRPort, DWORD dwUser)
{
    CNetSDKFunctions* pThis = (CNetSDKFunctions*)dwUser;
    if (pThis == NULL)
    {
        ASSERT( FALSE );
        return ;
    }
    //pThis->ReConnect(lLoginID, pchDVRIP, nDVRPort);
}

BOOL CNetSDKFunctions::InitSDK()
{
    long m_PlayerHandle;

    H264_DVR_GetLastError();
    H264_DVR_Init(NULL, 0);

            //Here it is :
    BOOL logResult = H264_DVR_Init( (fDisConnect) DisConnectBackCallFunc, (DWORD) this );
   ....
  }
```

And fDisConnect definition :

```
typedef void (CALL_METHOD *fDisConnect)(long lLoginID, char *pchDVRIP, long nDVRPort, unsigned long dwUser);
```

Comment: Apparently `DisConnectBackCallFunc` has several overloaded versions of it, you will need to use `static_cast` to select the desired one; I'd tell you how if you identified the overloads and which one you would want.

Comment: I am working on a from-scratch project, and DisConnectBackCallFunc has no overloaded version (if by overloaded you're mean other implementations)

Comment: What do `CALL_METHOD` and `LONG` resolve to?

Comment: I don't see how to implement this. I'm beginner in c++ ;)